# OpenGL и C++ на Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Учу OpenGL на C++. Сам работаю на Linux Mint.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки устанавливать и как компилировать OpenGL-программы на g++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLFW
http://www.glfw.org/

GLM
https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html

SOIL
http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html

GLEW неплохо подойдёт.

Мне этих хватает.

Comment: ещё обязателньо нужен `glew` либо другие враперы

Comment: нужен но не обязательно. http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html Хотя для начала неплохобы.

Comment: я поэтому и написал, либо другие загрузчики `opengl API`.

Comment: Можно и без них грузить вручную.

Comment: ну конечно можно, вот только зачем на это тратить время если цель другая ?

Comment: Чтобы не грузить либу лишнюю.

Comment: и что в этом плохого ? прилинковать готовую либу намного быстрее и практичнее, чем писать что то подобное с нуля, которое в конечном итоге скорее всего придётся точно также линковать к своему проекту

Comment: Ну если в глев есть ошибка то всё плохо будет. Например когда я скомпилил GLFW проект в линуксе то полетел ввод при тике больше 300 мс и пришлось устанавливать и компилить последнюю экспериментальную версию.

Comment: зачем компилировать glew они уже собранные есть в репозиториях

Comment: экспериментальных под линукс нет(4 месяца назад небыло)